# How to apply Nodal Analysis on this circuit?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws, nodal-analysis

[image: fig]

The two voltage sources are forming a supernode right?
should i take the resistance 6 ohms into consideration? How the solution will be?

Comment: Homework questions need to show an attempt at an answer in order to show us where you are stuck.

Comment: I want the way of solving, not the solution it self.

Comment: Also this is not included in the lesson and not a homework.

Comment: It's simple. You know that the sum of the currents in the 2, 3, and 4 ohm resistors must be zero. So solve for \$V\$ where \$\frac{V}{2}+\frac{V-10}{4}+\frac{\frac72 V-10}{3}=0\$. That's the voltage for the upper left side node. The rest just falls out. There are more complicated approaches. But that's the direct approach. (The \$\frac72 V-10\$ comes from simplifying \$V-10+5\cdot \frac{V}2\$.)

Comment: Just look at the schematic. It must be that the currents in the 2, 3, and 4 Ohm resistors sum to zero. Otherwise the universe destroys itself as the nodes above them accumulate charge and the universe comes to an end and blows up into a new big bang event. That can't be. So there's no other choice here. Luckily for us, nodes remain neutral and life goes on.

Comment: The 6 ohm resistor is irrelevant. You don't care about it.